# How to cube Doubles in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to complete this homework question.

Write a public static method named q3 that takes an ArrayList of Doubles as a parameter and returns an ArrayList of Doubles. The returned ArrayList will contain only

- the values from the input ArrayList that have a cube within 9602.0 of 32805.23 (ie. the 
  difference of the cube and 32001.00 is less than 9500.0)

I am confused on how to check whether the values from the ArrayList are within 9500 of 32001.00. Here is what I have so far.

```
public static ArrayList<Double> q3(ArrayList<Double> list){
ArrayList<Double> Val = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(Double num: list) {
    Double cubed= (Math.pow(num, 3));
    Double subT = 32001.23 - cubed;
```

I am very new to Java and ArrayLists and would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: *the difference of the cube and 32001.00 is less than 9500.0*: so you must compute the difference between the cube and 32001.00, and compare it to 9500.0. Why do you compute the difference between the cube and 32805.23? Read the statement. It's all in there.

Comment: _the values from the input ArrayList that have a cube within 9602.0 of 32805.23 (ie. the difference of the cube and 32001.00 is less than 9500.0)_. Are the values supposed to be within 9500 of 32001 or 9602 or 32805.23?

Answer (score 0):

> the difference of the cube and 32001.00 is less than 9500.0

This means that when you subtract the greater of `cubed, 32001.00` from the smaller of `cubed, 32001.00`, the result will be `9500` or less.

Another way of saying the same thing is that you want the absolute value of the difference `32001.00 - cubed` to be less than or equal to `9500`.

Apply [`Math.abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) to `subT`, compare the result to `9500`, and add `num` to the result if `abs` is smaller.